# Push Registry not working on nokia N86 after rebooting the phone; works on N97 and Expressmusic

Tags: java-me, push, nokia, n97

I have written a simple midlet that invokes itself after a socket connection from a server program. I am using Push Registry to do this. It works fine on all the test phones I have immediately after installing. but if I reboot the phone, the push registry stops working on N86 whereas it is working on the other test phones that I have viz. N97 and ExpressMusic 5800. Has anyone faced such a problem before? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

btw, after going a little deep into the specifications of these phones, I found out that though all the phones are MIDP 2.1, N86 has Symbian OS v9.3 and the rest two have v9.4. Can that be the reason for the behavior of N86 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a hard reset (press *#7370#) on the phone (N86) and everything is working properly! I still don't know what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

Find the documentation of the error in nokia page:

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KIJ001317_-_Push_registrations_for_Bluetooth_MIDlet_turns_off_in_the_latest_S60_3rd_Edition_devices

The phones that are affected are:
Nokia E75, Nokia N78, Nokia N79, Nokia N96, Nokia 5630 XpressMusic, Nokia 6720 Classic, Nokia 5800 XpressMusic

Worst of all, you say there is no solution.

Comment: Hi Galufo,

So you finally found it out. Thanks for sharing the link. but my problem was not with bluetooth, I am using SMS and it is working on XpressMusic 5800, it was N86 that it didn't work on (and its working perfectly after hard reset). Did you come across any page that described the same problem for SMS or socket triggered push registry?


btw, the link you gave isn't complete. I googled and found it out (just giving a reference for other readers): http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KIJ001317_-_Push_registrations_for_Bluetooth_MIDlet_turns_off_in_the_latest_S60_3rd_Edition_devices